# BackPress not working when recreate() is called

Tags: android

I'm facing an strange issue all I did was added recreate() in onActivityResult() and after that the back button seems to be not working.
I tried to override onBackPress() but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Add some code here ...!!!

Comment: in `backpressed()` put `finish()` as u are recreating the activity it will overwrite the stack entry

Comment: Already tried not working.

Comment: When you click back your new activity finish but not the old one.are you define any android:launchMode in your manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both singletask and singleInstance can work here but I've used singleTask as I don't wont to create a separate task

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and its working for me.

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Comment: Thanks but I've used singleTask.